# Which 'time' is used for the timeout by the subprocess module on UNIX/Linux OSes?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

Which time measurement is used for the `timeout` by the Python 3 `subprocess` module on UNIX/Linux OSes?

UNIX like OSes report 3 different times for process execution: `real`, `user`, and `system`. Even with processes that will be alive for only a few milliseconds the `real` time is often several hundred percent longer than the `user` and `system` time.

I'm making calls using `subprocess.call()` and `subprocess.check_output()` with the timeout set to a quarter of a second for processes that the `time` utility reports taking 2-18 milliseconds for the various times reported. There is no problem and my enquiry is purely out of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wall-clock time (`real`), not time spent in either userland (`user`) or the kernel (`system`).

You can test this yourself by running a process such as `sleep 60`, which uses almost no user or system time at all, and observing that it still times out.

Comment: Thanks. Ahh yes, I can indeed verify that by running: `subprocess.call(["sleep", "60"], timeout=1)`. Good idea, now why didn't I think of that. :)